# Check Push notification Availability Android

Tags: java, android, push-notification

Ok, going straight to the point. I want to check whether the device can received push notifications or can't. How can I achieve that?

Any help or idea to this question will be great.

Regards.

Comment: you need google play services to be installed in your device to receive and send push notifications.So check for google play services instead.

Comment: Is google play service only the requirement for receiving push notification? By the way, thank you so much for you response @AnirudhSharma!

Comment: i believe so.That's what written on the developers site.By the way you also require internet permissions

Comment: you may also check https://subassistant.freshdesk.com/support/articles/131296-i-m-not-receiving-push-app-notifications-